# Random variables, Correlation and expectation

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value, correlation

We know that if $E(X|Y) = E(X)$, then $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. I found out that the reverse statement is not always true, ie. $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, but $E(X|Y)$ is not equal to $E(X)$. But I don't get why... If I am right, can you give an example where this happens??

Comment: @Kolmogorov I'm sorry if I bothered anyone, but this doubt is about correlation and my previous one was about independence, so not the same thing

Comment: I'm sorry. My bad. Let me delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

$Y\sim N(0,1)$ and $X=Y^{2}$. Note that $E(X|Y)=Y^{2}$ and $EX=1$. Now $E(XY)=EY^{3}=0=(EX) (EY)$.